# Cost of an Azure Databricks cluster running but not executing any Spark app

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have been reading the Azure Databricks [pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/databricks/) but I can't find if there is any difference between the costs depending if the cluster is running a spark app or not.

I have a 2-node cluster that I use to upload a Spark application that, on an hourly basis, calculates certain elements and stores the result in a Databricks table. The table needs to be accessed by an external BI application, so the cluster needs to be up. Assuming that the cluster is running for a whole hour but only executing the Spark application for 5 minutes, am I going to be charged differently for the 5 minute execution time than for the other 55 minutes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a question for here,

- but assuming you are using 'pay-as-go' option and not 'reserved instances',

  - you will be charged the whole hour for compute resources & any ephemeral storage.

Any saved to storage is paid for continuously, but is pretty cheap. Like AWS, 'managed services' are more costly.